# Find Close Vertices in QGIS

Tags: qgis, error, topology, digitizing

I am trying to find digitizing errors in a line-layer. Obviously the snapping was not activated when the person who digitized created the lines.

[image]

As far as I know QGIS cannot find undershoots, so I try to find close vertices.
OpenJump has a tool called "Find Close Vertices" which helps finding some of the digitizing-errors. How could I archieve something like this in QGIS?

[image]

I tried to use v.clean with the break option to find the errors but this did not help much.

Test-data can be found here: https://gist.github.com/rdbath/104876de54fdfe0fc3ceed521220673e?short_path=f75c9b4

Answer (score 3):

Usually **GRASS v.clean - Snap** option does a great job, setting the `Threshold` (in your case `0.2 meters`) to cover the gap.

[image]

However, the result is not ideal. Lower branch was snapped up onto the upper branch, not to the right one.

[image]

A workaround is to (1) Snap with small tolerance to fill the small gap first, then (2) Snap again with larger tolerance to fill the larger gap.

**(1)** First snap by `Threshold = 0.1`

[image]

**(2)** Second snap (the `Cleaned` red line layer from the above is the input) by `Threshold = 0.25`

[image]

The new blue `Cleaned` line is the final output.

Comment: Thanks for this interesting idea. However I would prefer a solution which only detects "errors". The lines belong to a fibre-network planning and automatically snapped lines could result in wrong connections (unfortunally the distance of the gaps vary quite much in other datasets, so finding the right thresholds could be a game of luck).